# Is there a distributed approach for buffering API requests?

Tags: json, api, rest, architecture, microservices

I'm still learning how to use API's and would like to know what the wisest way to approach taking what I have ("A" in the diagram below) and refactoring it into what I'd like to have ("B" in the diagram below).

[image: The image uploaded to Imgur]

The main idea is that my current webapp reaches directly out to an external service via (their) API. I'd like to reduce how many calls my app makes to their service by making what I can only think of as a "buffer" that will periodically check in with that external service, update itself with copies of any new data available, and then make itself available directly to my webapp.

After some googling: It looks like I could use

- a protocol buffer; This seems like overkill and my understanding is that this is better for time-intensive applications with heavy data transfer between services
- a queue service
- a message service

Any ideas for where to start would be greatly appreciated! I am largely self taught in full stack applications and there hasn't been a whole lot of guidance up to this point regarding *how* to design systems at a conceptual level

Comment: The high-level term you're looking for is a _cache_.  Protocol buffers, a queue, and a message service aren't likely to be that directly useful here.

Answer (score 0):

The design will depend on the amount of data per API request, the rate of requests, and so on.

One possible solution is to use [temporal.io](https://temporal.io/) open source project which would allow implementing your logic as a simple piece of code. The Temporal service would make the application distributed and resilient.